Apparmor blocking NAS access
I upgraded my 510S laptop from 20.04 to 24.04. Now apparmor is giving me fits. I have a file server (NAS), a My Cloud EX-2 Ultra that contains most of my working files. This was a cold install of 24.04, backed up my home directory, installed from a USB drive.
It is accessed via this fstab entry
//172.23.0.252/Public /mnt/NAS cifs vers=2.1,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,noserverino,iocharset=utf8,nobrl 0 0

I could not save files to the NAS from GIMP, found this unexplained magic incantation which when entered into my .profile solved the GIMP problem.
snap connect gimp:removable-media :removable-media

Libre Office Writer is denying some (but not all) access to NAS text files. Message from Writer is can't create a lock file. DMESG shows about a dozen of these:
[  262.942755] audit: type=1400 audit(1722619614.300:245): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.libreoffice.writer" name="/proc/3650/mountinfo" pid=3650 comm="pool-soffice" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  262.942763] audit: type=1400 audit(1722619614.300:246): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.libreoffice.writer" name="/proc/3650/mounts" pid=3650 comm="pool-soffice" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

I don't see anything in /snap/libreoffice
jbh@510S:/snap/libreoffice/current$ ls
config  data-dir  etc  filebug.py  javasettings.py  lib  libreoffice.wrapper  meta  snap  usr  var

Can someone point me to a fix?

Please edit the question and add some details. How did you jump from 20.04 to 24.04? There must be steps missing for your question.

Cold install from a USB stick.

I/m pretty close to deleting this 24.04 install going back to 20.04. I cannot access my NAS server. 24.04 has made a total mess of app armor and is unuseable on my network.
